# How do you get value of select button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When clicking the select button, it doesn't enter in the function? Why is that? The console in the browser is empty.

**HTML:**

```
<select name="field_choice[]"
        id="field_choice_1"
        class="form-control field_choice">
    <option value="0" >Link</option>
    <option value="1">Text</option>
</select>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".field_choice").on("click",function(){
        console.log(1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you want change, not click

Comment: @epascarello It doesn't work either

Comment: my guess, you are binding before the element is rendered

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: It works for me... shows `1` every time you click the `select` element. Are you loading jQuery?

Comment: @freginold - yeah, I do - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

You can't forget to add jquery, I added so the script only runs when all the html has loaded and if you needed the value for when you clicked on it `$(".field_choice").val()`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function(){
        $(".field_choice").on("click",function(e){
            console.log($(".field_choice").val());
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".field_choice").on("change",function(){
    console.log(1);
});
```

```html
<select name="field_choice" id="field_choice_1" class="form-control field_choice">
    <option value="0" >Link</option>
    <option value="1">Text</option>
</select>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It would be on change not on click.

Comment: It should be rendered after window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Place the script in the very bottom of you body.

Surround it with an onload function:

```
$(document).load(function(){
  $(".field_choice").on("change",function(){
        console.log(1);
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".field_choice").on("change",function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="field_choice[]" id="field_choice_1" class="form-control field_choice">
    <option value="0" >Link</option>
    <option value="1">Text</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to wrap the jQuery commands between

```
$(function() {
```

and

```
});
```

This way you're always sure they get executed when all the DOM Elements (select, option, etc) are rendered (= exist).
If the commands are executed before, the selector won't fiend any .field_count element, therefore will have no effect.

Every "DOM-editing" jQuery command should be wrapped inside an anonymous function like this!

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` :

> The onclick event occurs when the pointing device button is clicked
>   over an element. This attribute may be used with most elements.

`onchange` :

> The onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

From what I can see you are looking to use `onchange` getting the value of the select list.

Your code works but, probably not how you intended

To get the value as per your HTML code, `<option value="0" >Link</option>` do as follows:

```
$(".field_choice").on("change",function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/88yo1zcy/

To get the text value do as follows:

```
$(".field_choice").on("change",function(){
    console.log($('option:selected').text());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r5dzvjqp/